# Modify existing column in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

How I can modify existing table column to NOT NULL in MariaDB.

I tried -

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY COLUMN EMP_ID SET NOT NULL;
```

I have also tried

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY EMP_ID NOT NULL;
```

But every time I am getting

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT 
NULL' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When modifying a column definition, you *must* include all the characteristics that you wish to keep -- such as `INT` or `VARCHAR(22)`.  That is, the `ALTER` statement must say exactly what the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to show.